# MultipartFormDataStreamProvider cannot read Stream

Tags: c#, .net, multipartform-data

I working with upload function in asp.net and doing this

```
string root = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data");
string imageName = "";
var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
try
{
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider); // error "Error reading MIME multipart body part." + Cannot access a disposed object.
 .... more code
```

I'm sure that I provided full permission for App_Data folder but still get this error. Could any body help me?

By the way, I already set

> maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />